# git aws.push returned error 403

Tags: amazon-web-services, git

I am working on getting git setup for my application on 'Elastic Beanstalk'. I've been following the instructions provided by Amazon.

After pushing the changes I get this error:

```
git aws.push

error: The requested URL returned error: 403 while accessing https://<Access Key Removed>:20130117T213945Z538f1c7baf8c89b4b547cb6717aabbaa7dfab3c52e0911d71e17b06765b922b2@git.elasticbeanstalk.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/54696d73546573744170706c69636174696f6e/commitid/62323130316462646264373436303536343265633861333035633133633265666466393633303133/environment/54696d7374657374656e7669726f6e6d656e74/info/refs?service=git-receive-pack
fatal: HTTP request failed
```

Here's my `.config` file:

```
git config -l

credential.helper=osxkeychain
user.name=Tim xxxxxxxxxx
user.email=xxxxxxxxx@gmail.com
core.bare=false
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=true
core.logallrefupdates=true
core.ignorecase=true
aws.endpoint.us-east-1=git.elasticbeanstalk.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
aws.endpoint.ap-northeast-1=git.elasticbeanstalk.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com
aws.endpoint.eu-west-1=git.elasticbeanstalk.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com
aws.endpoint.us-west-1=git.elasticbeanstalk.us-west-1.amazonaws.com
aws.endpoint.us-west-2=git.elasticbeanstalk.us-west-2.amazonaws.com
aws.endpoint.ap-southeast-1=git.elasticbeanstalk.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com
aws.endpoint.ap-southeast-2=git.elasticbeanstalk.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com
aws.endpoint.sa-east-1=git.elasticbeanstalk.sa-east-1.amazonaws.com
alias.aws.elasticbeanstalk.remote=!.git/AWSDevTools/aws.elasticbeanstalk.push --remote-url
alias.aws.elasticbeanstalk.push=!.git/AWSDevTools/aws.elasticbeanstalk.push
alias.aws.elasticbeanstalk.config=!.git/AWSDevTools/aws.elasticbeanstalk.config
alias.aws.push=!git aws.elasticbeanstalk.push
alias.aws.config=!git aws.elasticbeanstalk.config
```

I don't really know what else to check or do and let me know if I can provide you with additional information.

Comment: HTTP 403?  I would check that the account that you're using has proper permissions.  Are you using a set of keys from an IAM account?  If so, double check that you have the correct permissions (or policy) associated with the account.

Comment: Where would I check the permissions? I'm not using IAM keys, in the documentation there's a link to the "Access Credentials". I followed that link and got the Key and Secret Key from there.   http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_PHP.sdlc.html

Comment: Yes, the main account keys will give you full access (or should, anyhow).  I'm not really sure how to help. Have you tried posting in the AWS support forums?  This might need the attention of AWS staff to resolve.

Comment: Yeah... I posted there. Haven't heard anything yet...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I didn't have the HTTPS (443) port open in my Security Group. Working like a dream now that that's adjusted.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, my computer's time had gone out of sync with the server time for some reason. Happens once in a while, I run Ubuntu in a virtual machine. Fixed the time manually, and committed as usual.